# Change decimal commas to points in QGIS created dbf-file

Tags: qgis-2, shp2pgsql

There is a bug in the QGIS desktop application where two merged shapefiles produce a dbf-file with commas as decimal separators.

I need to have this merged file imported to PostGIS database, but the import using `shp2pgsql` and `psql` fails to error `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "6817749,945313"`

The QGIS version used is the one in Ubuntu 16.04-repositories (2.8.6-Wien)

The bug is a bit old https://issues.qgis.org/issues/8332

**How can I update the dbf-file to have the correct decimal separators?**

Comment: I am not an Ubuntu user, but I think there is an updated version for QGIS as it is now 2.14.16 for LTR and 2.18.10 for latest version. Have you tried to update your QGIS version?

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the Ubuntu repositories do contain a much older version. I'll try to update according to https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#linux

Comment: I finally managed to install a newer version of the QGis software on my system using a Personal Package Archive https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa. This installed version 2.14.1-Essen, which seemingly doesn't have the issue any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can try is the following:

- In the field calculator add a new field with **type real**
- as expression try:  `replace(tostring("your_field"), ',', '.')`
- Drop your old field which caused the problem, after you checked, that everything worked out

Another option:

- Again create a new field in field calculator with **type string**
- Use the expression: `replace("your_field", ',', '.')`
- Drop your field which causes the error
- in The Postgis database cast the field with `CAST(my_newfield AS real)` or any [suitable type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype.html)

Comment: The first one worked great. Although I used the Attribute table to display the data first, and then used the "Toggle editing mode" before writing the replace-commands to edit the columns in place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a system that supports GNU sed (most do), I have had great success with sed scripts.  I use it to "untruncate" shapefile dbf names that are shortened with exporting to shapefiles. The PostgreSQL database has the names in the format of the original database.

shp2pgsql scripts are often huge, and sed runs much faster that text-editing search and replace.